# How to read and write a file using python?

Tags: python, django

I want to write the text (which I get from AJAX) to a file, and then read it.

Comment: The tutorial <a href="http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files">covers this</a>.

Comment: Any reason, why you want to re-read it again after fetching? (Like, you want to append new data and read the whole file...)

Comment: @Boldewyn: Presumably to send it back out again at a later time. Appending doesn't require reading what's already in the file.

Comment: Hello everybody, 
please my English is not so good.

 I want to write the text (which I get from AJAX) to a file,i found this example in Ineternet ,and it is interressant ,but i don't no how i can test that.Please can u tell me  witch Labrary i want  bevor it works ? or can u give me some example how i can do that ,i will very happy.
 
I thank U in advance
Denis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code for read the content from a file

```
handle=open('file','r+')
var=handle.read()
print var
```

> If you want to read a single line use
>   the readline(). If you want to read
>   the whole      lines in the file use
>   the readlines() also

The following code for writing the content to the file

```
handle1=open('file.txt','r+')
handle1.write("I AM NEW FILE")
handle1.close()
```

Comment: python doesn't terminate in semi-colons.

Answer (score 11):

If you can use this in Django view... try somethink like this:

```
def some_view(request):
    text = request.POST.get("text", None)
    if text is not None:
        f = open( 'some_file.txt', 'w+')
        f.write(text)
        f.close()
    return HttpResponse()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
f = open( 'filename.txt', 'w+' )
f.write( 'text' )
f.close()

f = open( 'filename.txt', 'r' )
for line in f:
    print( line )
f.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this out

```
with open("file.txt", "r+") as file:

     for i in file:
         file.write(i + "\n")
file.close
```

Comment: you don't need close if you're using with