# Calling function from fortran module in django causes AttributeError

Tags: python, django, fortran

I have a simple subroutine written in `Fortran`. Just for testing reasons it is as simple as this:

```
!test.f90
subroutine test()
end subroutine test
```

It compiles well with `gfortran` and with `f2py`. I compile it with `f2py` like so:

```
$ f2py -m test -c test.f90
```

If I go to `python`, I can import it and everything works ok:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.test() # ok. nothing as expected and with no errors
```

In `django` I have an app called just `myapp`. It has a view which looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from numpy import *
from test import *  # the module itself imports ok, I get no errors

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    #test.test() # but if I try to call a function from it, I get an error
    context = RequestContext(request,{})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

The error message is: `AttrubuteError at /myapp/ test`. PS. I'm a `python` and `django` newbee, so I guess I could make some "stupid" error.

**EDIT**

Now, thanks to `laike9m`, I manage to call a fortran function, at least I do not have error any longer. But at the same time it seems as if the function does nothing. I mean this. I changed my fortran function a little bit, so that it now writes some stuff to a file. If I check it in pure `python`, I see that it works - a file is modified. But if I call it in django, it does not modify it. So, my codes now look like this:

```
!fortran code
!test.f90
subroutine test()
  open(1,file='test.txt',status='replace')
  write(1,*) "Hello, Django! My name is Fortran."
  close(1)
end subroutine test


from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from numpy import *
from test import * # it's ok

def index(request):
    template = loader.get_template('myapp/index.html')
    test() # no error any longer, but the function itself does nothing
    context = RequestContext(request,{})
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

So, my question is how to check whether fortran module works or not?

**EDIT**

Thanks to **laike9m** and **Vladimir**, I finally did it. The problem was in the path to the file. I had to put the file right in the root folder of the project.

Comment: Don't use unit number `1` or anything smaller than 11. They can have a special purpose and be pre-connected.

Comment: Thanks, Vladimir, I will check it now

Comment: @Vladimir Unfortunately, that does not help. It still has no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `import test`, then it's `test.test()`
If you `from test import *`, then it's `test()`

See [The import system](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html)

Comment: Could you, please, have a look at my updated question?

Comment: @Jacobian I'm sorry but I'm not familiar with fotran. Is it working when you type in REPL?

Comment: @Jacobian You asked `how to check whether fortran module works or not?`, but this is just what I want to ask.

Comment: I mean it works in python, when I go right to console and type `import test...`. but in Django, when I call the very same function, it has no effect, it just does nothing.

Comment: @Jacobian So what's the effect of `test()`?

Comment: It writes `"Hello, Django! My name is Fortran."` to `test.txt`.

Comment: @Jacobian I have to say I don't know the reason. Writing files in Django views should work as in normal Python script, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491141/how-to-read-and-write-a-file-using-python. Maybe you should ask someone who knows f2py.

Comment: Oh, finally, I did it. The problem was in the path to the file. When I put it right in the root folder of `django` project, then I made it work. Thank you, laike9m! Your helped me a lot!