# How to simplify the process of saving files in python

Tags: python-3.x, easing

How to read and write files in python easier? By one line? What variants of function can be for:

```
with open(file='file_name', mode='r', encoding='utf8') as f:
    F = f.read()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read and write a file using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491141/how-to-read-and-write-a-file-using-python)

Comment: I think a lot of people knew how to read and write. I try to share easer way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making it easier to read json

```
# pip install varname
def read_j(file_name, encod='utf8'):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding=encod) as f:
        F = json.load(f)
        return F
```

Making it easier to write json

```
def write_j(data, file_name=None, type_='w', indent=4, ensure_ascii=False, encod='utf8'):
    if file_name == None:
        file_name = varname.nameof(data, frame=2) + '.json'

    with open(file_name, type_, encoding=encod) as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=indent, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii)
```

Making it easier to read file

```
def read_f(file_name, encod='utf8'):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding=encod) as f:
        F = f.read()
        return F
```

Making it easier to write file

```
def write_f(data, file_name=None, type_='w', encod='utf8'):
    # print(data)
    if file_name == None:
        file_name = varname.nameof(data, frame=2)
        if type(data) == list or type(data) == dict:
            write_j(data, file_name+'.json')
        elif type(data) == str:
            file_name = file_name + '.txt'
            with open(file_name, type_, encoding=encod) as f:
                f.write(data)
        elif type(data) == bytes:
            with open(file_name, mode='wb', encoding=None) as f:
                f.write(data)
    else:
        with open(file_name, type_, encoding=encod) as f:
            f.write(data)
```